# Why isnt the interceptor class working in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have an interceptor class:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(req);
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

I added this class to main app.module as provider:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NoopInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
```

So, I tried to get http response as:

```
console.log(req);
```

It returns me nothing.

Http request is:

```
return this.http.post('path', data, options)
      .map(res => (<any>res)._body === '' ? {} : res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

I changed Http to HttpService. It rewquires to add in providers. I added:

```
 providers: [
    HttpService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NoopInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
```

Now it tells to: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend!`

Comment: Added example of HTTP request

Comment: Did you subscribe to it?

Comment: Where and how? I have only code that I posted

Comment: `return this.http.post('path', data, options)
      .map(res => (<any>res)._body === '' ? {} : res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError).subscribe(() > {})` Or subscribe to method that return the code above

Comment: Are you sure to use this.http : HttpClient and not Http ? If you use type of Http instead of HttpClient your interceptor don't work.

Comment: No I use `Http` for requests

Comment: Your http need this type: constructor(private http: HttpClient){} not constructor(private http: Http){}. Your interceptor catch all request from type of HttpClient from angular4.3 not type of Http from angular2

Comment: I get `core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for HttpService!` When I made changes

Comment: I can't help you whitout more code.

Comment: I updted question

Comment: You're doing something wrong. It's very simple https://plnkr.co/edit/R9toF0v2nOmFUHsrif1a?p=preview

Comment: I tried this library, it requires HttpService: `https://github.com/yulonh/ng2-http-interceptor`